# How to make the Graphics move ONLY inside the JFrame and not outside the bounds of the JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, game-development

I am currently developing a `Catch the Falling Object`-type game but the problem for now is the player (aka the one who catches the objects). When I move through the left side and hit the bounds of the window, it is sending the player to `x - 1`, but when I go to the right side (even though I put the code as `if (x > windowBoundRight){ x = x - 1 }` though it is still moving outside the window bounds. Can anyone help me? (Note: there are no errors btw)

This is the code:

```java
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Game extends JPanel implements ActionListener, KeyListener {

    public int x = 0, y = 0, velx = 0, vely = 0;
    public boolean hitAnObject = false;
    public Color c = Color.BLACK;
    Timer timer = new Timer(5, this);


    public Game() {
        timer.start();
        setBackground(Color.CYAN);
        addKeyListener(this);
        setFocusable(true);
        setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g){
        super.paint(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.fillRect(x, y, 50, 50);
        g.drawString("X = " + x + "Y = " + y, 0, 0);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        repaint();
        x += velx;
        y += vely;
    }

    public void left() {
        velx = -5;
        vely = vely + 0;
    }

    public void right() {
        velx = 5;
        vely = vely + 0;
    }

    public void up() {
        vely = -5;
        velx = velx + 0;
    }

    public void down() {
        vely = 5;
        velx = velx + 0;
    }
    public void stopMovement_UP() {
        vely = 0;
        velx = velx + 0;
    }
    public void stopMovement_DOWN() {
        vely = 0;
        velx = velx + 0;
    }
    public void stopMovement_LEFT() {
        velx = 0;
        vely = vely + 0;
    }
    public void stopMovement_RIGHT() {
        velx = 0;
        vely = vely + 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        int keyCode = e.getKeyCode();
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT || keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_A) {
            left();
            if (x < 0) {
                x = 0;
            }
        }
        else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT || keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_D) {
            right();
            //checck if the graphic aka player moves out of the boundary
        }
        else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN || keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_S) {
            down();
        }
        else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_UP || keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_W) {
            up();
            if (y < 0) {
                y = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) { }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) { 
        int keyCode = e.getKeyCode();
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT || keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_A) {
            stopMovement_LEFT();
            if (x < 0) {
                x = 0;
            }
        }
        else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT || keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_D) {
            stopMovement_RIGHT();
            if (x > 436) {
                x = x + 2;
            }
        }
        else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN || keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_S) {
            stopMovement_DOWN();
        }
        else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_UP || keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_W) {
            stopMovement_UP();
            if (y < 0) {
                y = 0;
            }
        }
        
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Game game = new Game();
        game.getBackground();
    }

}
```

Comment: Also this script is only the movement I haven't made the script of falling object

Comment: but how can I check if it is within the Game panel?

Answer (score 0):

In method `actionPerformed`, you are changing values of *x* and *y* but you are not checking whether the calculated values are within the bounds of the `Game` panel.

In method `paint` (in class `Game`) the *x* and *y* coordinates are within the coordinate space of the panel, i.e. `Game`. The *x* coordinate of the left edge of `Game` is 0 (zero). The *x* coordinate of the right edge is the width of `Game` which you can retrieve via method [getWidth](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JComponent.html#getWidth()).

Similarly, the *y* coordinate of the top edge (of `Game`) is zero and the *y* coordinate of the bottom edge is the height of `Game` which you can retrieve via method `getHeight`.

Hence you compare the calculated value of variables `x` and `y` (in method `actionPerformed`) with the width and height (of `Game`) to see whether they are outside the bounds of `Game`.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
    x += velx;
    if (x > getWidth() || x < 0) {
        // 'x' is outside of the bounds
    }
    y += vely;
    if (y > getHeight() || y < 0) {
        // 'y' is outside of the bounds
    }
    repaint();
}
```

I think that you should call method `repaint` **after** you have calculated the new values for `x` and `y` (and not before, as in the code in your question).

I don't know how you want the player to move once he hits one of the edges (of `Game`) so I only wrote a comment in the `if` conditions in the above code.

If you haven't already done so, I recommend reading [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) lesson in *Creating a GUI With Swing* trail of Oracle's Java tutorials.

Comment: In the comments `// 'x' is outside of bounds` I just gotta do `x = x - 1`?

Comment: @Athran123_ If you want the player to move in the opposite direction once he hits the right edge, then yes, you can do `x--`. And when the player hits the left edge, you do `x++`.